# apple push notification doesn't go through if specific device id is included

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have a push service that works fine except when certain device ids are included. My test isn't bulk, I'm only sending to 2 or 3 devices. When I only send it to the 2 devices it works fine, but including the 3rd makes all 3 fail. The feedback service returns only an empty array. What could I be doing wrong?

It seems like my only option now is to loop through all the device ids and send each out one by one, ugh...

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd device token is probably invalid (it will be invalid if you try to use a production device token for sandbox push or vica versa). If you send an invalid token first, it will close the connection and the following tokens won't reach Apple until you create a new socket and re-send them.